# Get any key from keyboard in C++ including keys like control

Tags: c++, windows, input

I'm programming in C++ and have run into a wall.

I need to get input from the keyboard.  The problem is that I also need to get input from keys like control, scroll lock, windows key, etc.  I also need to be able to differentiate between the numpad and regular numbers 0-9.

I tried using _getch().  While it can get keys like arrow keys and the numpad, I can't get keys like control, shift and scroll lock.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: None of this can be done in standard C++, it requires OS-specific code, and will even depend on whether you're in a GUI or using the console.

Comment: This is highly platform-specific. What platfrom are you programming for?

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way to do this because C++ does not assume the system even has all those things.

A good solution for what you are trying to do is the SDL library. Look here:
https://www.libsdl.org/

Answer (score 0):

I see the word "windows key" so I'm assuming you're programming for Windows

Use WinAPI [`ReadConsoleInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput)

```
HANDLE hInput = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
INPUT_RECORD ir;
DWORD read;
if (!ReadConsoleInput(hInput, &ir, 1, &read) || read == 0) {
    // Something went wrong
}
if (ir.EventType == KEY_EVENT) {
    // Do stuff here
}
```

Refer to [`KEY_EVENT_RECORD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/key-event-record-str) for more information. You can get control keys states from

```
ir.Event.KeyEvent.dwControlKeyState
```

[This is an example provided by Microsoft.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/reading-input-buffer-events)